# How to do batch delete from the sql table in spring boot. Service Implementation

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

How to do batch delete from the sql table in spring boot.

I have many to many relationship intermediate table. I want to remove few data based on the similar request payload.

```
{
    user : “SomUser”,
    transaction : [“A”,”B”]
}
```

Now here is my controller and here I am able to get the request payload from the request and I am getting input and passing to service.

```
@PostMapping(“/remove”)
public EntityModel<TrasnDTO> removeByUserId(
        @RequestBody TrasnDTO input
) throws IOException {

    TrasnDTO someVar = transeService. deleteTransByUser(input);

    return  null; // will write once it complete
    
}
```

Here is my Service Interface

```
TrasnDTO deleteTransByUser(TrasnDTO input);
```

Implementation :

```
 @Override
    
    public TrasnDTO deleteTransByUser(TrasnDTO input){
       for(int counter=0; counter<input.getTrans().size(); counter++){
       UUID transVal = input.getTrans().get(counter);
       transRepository.removeUser(input.getUserId(), transVal);
     }
        return null;
    }
```

In My TransRepo :

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("delete from trans_user where user_id = :user_id and trans_id = :trans_id)
void removeUser(UUID user_id, UUID trans_id);
```

My question is how should I write in impl method to go to repository and delete that. I am using Java 11.

I am getting error as I don't have specific repo for trans_user

Error : Cannot resolve method 'removeUser' in 'TransRepository

Comment: I would provide a method to delete multiple transactions based on id or whatever your input contains. Just use a where-condition that accepts a list of elements - of just delete all transactions for that user if that meets your requirements.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for comment. I have written a logic for serviceImpl, can you please check it correct way to do or not. Then I have written query in Repository, but getting error, what would be the correct way to write repo.

Comment: Well. it's certainly one way to do it. I'd probably use a different approach but let's not get sidetracked here - if it works for you that's fine. No speaking of "if it works": if you're getting an error you've made a mistake. That's it. Since I lack details, e.g. the error you get, your data model etc., I can't say more than this.

Comment: @Thomas yes, I don't have a data model for `trans_user ` table since I am using intermediate table as `many to many relationship`. Can you please help me with different approach. and do I need to create another data model(as what i get in tutorial is no). or different repo.

Comment: @Thomas Updated error in Question.

Comment: "Cannot resolve method 'removeUser' in 'TransRepository" - that looks like an error in your build or a problem with visibility. If your IDE already complains then it's probably the latter (probably missing the `public` or `protected` modifier - depending on your code structure). If it's the former then make sure your build updates all your code. If the error persists then there's probably some other error or warning being logged before that - this might hint at the cause.